# Rewrite www. in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, express

I want to rewrite http://www.xyz.com/abc to http://xyz.com/abc.
How can that be done in Node.js.

I'm using node-http-proxy on port 80 and forward requests to Express on port 3000.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a 301 with appropriate location headers if request hostname == www.xyz.com

The browser will do the rest.

You can do it on either side of the proxy. But i'd assume it makes sense to do something like this:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //
  // Put your custom server logic here, then proxy
  //
  if (req.headers.host == 'www.xyz.com') {
     res.writeHead(301, {'Location': 'xyz.com/' + req.url}); 
     res.end();
  }
  else {
     proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 9000
     });
  }

}).listen(80);
```

Comment: The path should also be redirected. The host header can only contain a host name. I edited my post to clarify.

Comment: a 301 will still work, just pass the path info in the location header as well, all this data should be available in the request object.

Comment: Thanks. I had to write "res.writeHead(301, {'Location': 'http://xyz.com/' + req.url}); res.end();" instead of "res.send(...)", because send() doesn't exist.

Comment: hmm whoops. i think it was supposed to just be .end *typo

Comment: In my Express app I had to write it like `res.writeHead(301, {'Location': '//xyz.com' + req.url});` Because the redirect needed a protocol (using relative protocol), and req.url already included an `/` at the end. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using nginx as proxy..